# Print two report in Odoo8

Tags: odoo

How can I generate and download two report with a single action from python code.

```
def print_reports(self, cr, uid, ids, context):
    'I have to do it here'
    ...
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.report.xml',
        'report_name': 'certificate_of_origin',
        'datas': datas,
    }
```

I need to print two versions of `certificate_of_origin` with one click, but I can print just one version each time.

Comment: Why don't you want to print all you want in a single report?

Comment: OK, but you want to create two different files right?

Comment: @zetysz and put two options (each one to download each report) is not a good way?

Comment: Feel free to comment when you vote down( `UnKNoWN`).

Answer (score -1):

I dont think its possible using the current reporting. 2 years back i have done the same thing by using jasper reports. and using the sub reports functionalities.